# How to remove background of image during runtime in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, uiimage, background-color

[image]

I have an image in UIImageView. Those images are generally of clothes or accessories captured from camera on plain backgrounds. Now, I have to give a functionality to users so that they can remove the background from the actual image which is being shown. Something like what is shown in the picture here. As the slider will move the background will start getting removed more and more. Something like the 'instant alpha' brush in the Preview application available in Mac OS X. I wish to do this in native iPhone app.

I know I'll require some algorithm for image processing to do this. Does anyone have anything helpful which I can refer or use in order to get this done? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @Dip Dhingani have you solved this

Comment: Sorry, nothing has worked for me yet. :(

Comment: @DipDhingani have you been able to achieve this ? Please let me know i am stuck on the same issue

Answer (score 1):

You can render your image in some context, than change all points you need to the color you want, get image from your context and display it again.
[This](http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color/) link should help you to get color of a pixel in context.
Note, that this method is too slow, so I think you should remember all positions of pixels you
need to change to make your app a bit faster.